# ReactJS Events from the EventListener Don't Update The View

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, webview

I am basically trying to use the event listeners and add an event for the 'message' event which gets external events when this app is a webview in some mobile app.

The problem is that the react component DOES NOT update when the event comes in. I can identifiy that the event does come into my event listener function however, literally the react component DOES NOT update even if i do setState.

Here's my code:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css'; 

    var showIfEventHappenedAndReactUpdated = false;

    class App extends Component {

        componentDidMount() {

           //event listener to get events from external views
           //when this app is used as a webview for example
           document.addEventListener('message', function(e){

              //I can see the event coming through here
              //However, the react component itself doesn't update
              showIfEventHappenedAndReactUpdated = true;

              //I have even tried putting a this.setState({}) here but it doesn't work...as it doesn't update the react-component

           }) 
        }

      render() {

        if(showIfEventHappenedAndReactUpdated){
            return (
              <div className="App">
                <p>Event Occured and React Updated</p>
              </div>
            );
        }else{
            return (
               <div className="App">
                <p>Event DID NOT OCCUR YET</p>
               </div>
            );
        }

      }
    }

    export default App;
```

BUT if I get the 'p' tag internally like this

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css'; 



    class App extends Component {

        componentDidMount() {

           //event listener to get events from external views
           //when this app is used as a webview for example
           document.addEventListener('message', function(e){

              document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = "EVENT OCCURED"
           }) 
        }

      render() {
            return (
              <div className="App">
                <p>Event HAS NOT Occured</p>
              </div>
            );
        }

      }
    }

    export default App;
```

THEN it works. The only line change was

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = "EVENT OCCURED"
```

However, I need to actually update the react view instead of changing the text inside a raw DOM element.

What do i need to do in order to achieve that?

Comment: I haven't started ReactJS yet but i have read document and found that React Will Render DOM(React Component) when state properties changes so if you are use event listener than component will not change. You have to update any state value and it work fine.

Comment: @YogeshPatel i tried doing this.setState({}) yet it still didnt' update the component

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you getting an error if you try to setState in the event handler? addEventListener will set your this to the target the handler was bound to, which should be document in your case. Unless your document somehow has a setState method, this should be throwing an error.

Simply using an arrow function should fix it, or explicitly binding your handler to the current this when you are adding it as event listener.

If you are not getting an error and binding your function is not helping, try to console log this.setState just before adding event listener and inside the event listener and check if they are the same function. Alternately, try to add a callback to your setState to check if it's called.

Comment: tried using the arrow function and binding the callback....still doesn't update – Zunair Syed just now   edit

Comment: I will try to see if they're the same function using the console.log as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function's this is not bound to the react component, thus setState is undefined.  console.log(this) inside your callback to see.

To fix it, either bind the callback's this (.bind(this)) or use an arrow function if you have babel and whatnot set up.

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 problems in your code as it is at the time of writing this:

1. Your function in the event listener is not bound to your react element. As others have said, using the arrow syntax will fix this.
2. You're updating a non state variable. React will only render your component under 3 conditions: it's passed new props, you call setState() (with a new state, and you have to have returned a state in your constructor), or you call this.forceUpdate(). Changing a global variable will not cause a render.

Comment: hey, so the arrow function did not fix it. also i have previously tried setState({my states here}) and now just tried this.forceUpdate(). None have worked :(

Answer (score -1):

First, `showIfEventHappenedAndReactUpdated` isn't part of the component's state so when you update it, the component isn't aware that it needs to update. In your component add a constructor method something like this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { showIfEventHappenedAndReactUpdated: false };
}
```

Then update the value with `this.setState({showIfEventHappenedAndReactUpdated : true})`. This will make the component render again, and it will use the new value.

Second, the callback function isn't bound to the component's scope, and creates a new scope when it's called. Either use `.bind(this)` on the function call like this:

```
const callback = function(e){
    //do stuff
}
document.addEventListener('message', callback.bind(this));
```

Or you can use an arrow function, which doesn't create its own scope like this:

`document.addEventListener('message', (e)=>{ //do stuff };`

Comment: have tried both, can confirm they do not make a difference...react component does not update